# Did a movie give the final blow to the usage of the term "negro"?

Tags: terminology, offensive-language

While rewatching the famous movie "Guess Who's Coming to Dinner" I noticed that the term "negro" instead of "black" was often used. The following is a sentence taken from the movie.

From [Guess Who's Coming to Dinner](http://www.eslnotes.com/movies/pdf/guess-whos-coming-to-dinne.pdf):

> "He thinks you’re gonna faint because he’s a Negro".

the following source notes that:

> - “Negro” is the very dated word for a black person, which quickly died out in the years immediately following the release of this movie.

(www.eslnotes.com)

Also [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=negro) suggests that the term was replaced by "black" in the late 1960s.

> - because of its perceived association with white-imposed attitudes and roles ***the word was ousted late 1960s in this sense by "Black".***

Given the subject of the movie was the  representation of the controversial subject of interracial marriage during the [Civil Rights Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Civil_Rights_Movement_(1954%E2%80%931968)), I guess the terminology in the movie was very carefully chosen. This leads me to think that when the movie was released, the term "negro" was still a "politically correct" one, but for a very short time though.

Given the [immediate  popularity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guess_Who%27s_Coming_to_Dinner) and success of the movie, is there evidence that the film itself actually contributed to the change in usage and the emergence of "black" as a more commonly accepted term?

Comment: Wait, what? Saying the use of the term *Negro* faded after the release of the film is a very far cry from saying the film is reponsible for the the decline, especially considering terminology is not a central focus of the dialog.

Comment: @choster - well, the period is about the same, is it just a coincidence? It struck me how often the term is used in the movie, which, after so many years of "black" , it really seems strange  for a movie like that.

Comment: What *coincidence*? That a term is used matter-of-factly in a movie, then falls out of usage in broader society later on?

Comment: The movie was released in January 1968 and the term was "ousted" in the late '60s. Has the movie, which was a huge success, contributed to it? -  "*Guess Who's Coming to Dinner was a box-office hit in 1968 throughout the United States, **including in Southern states where it was traditionally assumed that few white filmgoers would want to see any film with black leads***". (Wikipedia)

Comment: The movie is not about terminology. If anything, it would have extended the use of the term in polite society.

Comment: This will be very speculative to answer. Even if there are mass-media articles about the movie and the term in the couple years following it with someone explicitly writing 'That movie made me use another word". That's only one person's evidence and can't show cause for all. We could only conjecture, or conjecture that the movie itself was already out of date when released.

Comment: @choster / the movie was and still is emblematic of that period about interracial marriage. I do think that every single word was carefully chosen.

Comment: I suspect, without convenient sources, that the change in the acceptable term and the release of the film were both effects of a shift in attitudes. Hollywood in the 50s wasn't exactly a stronghold of progressive attitudes. I doubt it can be settled one way or the other, but as it's still an interesting question (i.e. +1) I wouldn't mind being proved wrong.

Comment: The  rather elderly couple whose daughter was engaged to marry Sidney Poitier, wonderful actor by the way, were... *elderly*. It's only natural that they used a term which was common, and familiar to *them*, since the 1930s and 1940s (at least). The question is whether the doctor, the very young girl's fiancé,  described himself as being black or negro. This I do not remember.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - actually the term "negro" is often used also by the more emancipated  young daughter. In any case, if the term had had a clear offensive nuance, I really doubt it would  have been used in conversations in the movie.

Comment: John Prentice: *Dad... Dad, you're my father. I'm your son. I love you. I always have and I always will. But you think of yourself as a colored man. I think of myself as a man*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, coloured and black are also used , but negro is the term more often used. You can notice that because it really sounds...odd.

Comment: Many things contributed to it. Not one single thing.

Comment: @Lambie - of course, but a successful movie and its language may  have a great influence on people, probably more than street marches and sit-in meetings.

Comment: I would not say that the movie had nothing to do with the demise of the word, but the movie came out at a critical period in the evolution of the language of race, and it was quite intentionally staged to focus on race issues among "polite" society.  At the time there was considerable turmoil over the "proper" terminology (it's still not settled), and many factors were contributing to that turmoil.  The movie may have advanced by a month or so the demise of "negro", but it's highly unlikely that it was a deciding factor in that demise.

Comment: @HotLicks - well, given its popularity and the fact that it was  well received  by the general  public (the black one included), it may have well have had an influence in that respect. As you rightly pointed out...the movie came out at a critical point in the evolotion of the languag of race.

Comment: Note that you can't really discuss "negro" without discussing two other terms:  "nigger" and "nigruh".  "Nigger", of course, of course, is the term that was long considered "impolite", and commonly used pejoratively, but "nigruh" (approximate phonetic spelling) was a term which split the difference between "nigger" and "negro" and which Southern whites often claimed was non-prejudicial (because they were supposedly just saying "negro" with a Southern accent) but which was easily read as an attempt to "sanitize" "nigger".  So "negro" suffered guilt by association, and ...

Comment: ... many African Americans and their white sympathizers were willing to accept "black" when it was advanced, even though it had previously been used pejoratively.

Comment: When has a movie dealt a "final blow" to anything?

Comment: @Clare - movies may influence social behaviour and language, especially the most popular ones.

Comment: Kindly provide an example in which a popular movie dealt a final blow to anything. (Please exclude official propaganda films, such as those produced by the third Reich.)

Comment: @Clare - you already downvoted the question. Be happy with that if you don't want understand the meaning. Please see the first answer, it may help you understand.

Comment: To *deal a death blow* and *contributed to the change in usage* are not synonymous. I think you should clarify which one you are asking about. Probably the title should be changed.

Comment: @Clare - probably, and your attitude too.

Comment: There's a certain plausibility to the question but you really'd have to consider what evidence there is to support it. You'd have to check all the other movies at the time to see if they used or did not use whichever name in appropriate circumstances and if any of these movies were mentioned explicitly for this usage in the popular media at the time. That seems like dissertation level research.

Comment: @Mitch - I agree, and I realize that no definitive answer is possible. The point I want to make is that the movie was undoubtedly emblematic, in that it was based on a very sensitive issue at that time (interracial marriage) and the cast chosen was not accidentally a strong one for that time (Hepburn, Tracy etc.). I think it was a strong message from Hollywood. I

Comment: @Josh If you have to pick a year when saying "black" became more acceptable than saying "Negro", I think it would be 1972, based upon this article http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1972/02/27/page/29/article/vernon-jarrett-black-pride-in-color-heritage-is-not-new  which explains that on the south side of Chicago, politicians are getting advice to definitely not say "colored" and preferably not say "Negro" when addressing Black audiences there.  But this was far from a final blow.  More like a half-way point.

Comment: @Josh OK. I think the strong message received was one about marriage rather than what mainstream people should call a minority (specially since the choice of labels and preference were never mentioned).

Comment: @Mitch - you may be right, but language is an important part of the process of integration, and a marriage between a black and a white was probably better received than one between Negro and a white.

Comment: @Josh Sure, words change thoughts. If someone tells me about a dove and a pigeon I think of two mostly different birds. But looking at them side by side, I couldn't tell you the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to this article](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2010/01/when_did_the_word_negro_become_taboo.html), it is more likely due to the influential work of civil-rights figure [Stokely Carmichael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokely_Carmichael):

> When did the word *Negro* become socially unacceptable?
>
> It started its decline in 1966 and was totally uncouth by the mid-1980s. The turning point came when Stokely Carmichael [coined the phrase *black power*](http://www.interchange.org/Kwameture/nytimes111698.html) at a 1966 rally in Mississippi. Until then, *Negro* was how most black Americans described themselves. But in Carmichael's speeches and in his landmark 1967 book, [*Black Power: The Politics of Liberation in America*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679743138), he persuasively argued that the term implied black inferiority. Among black activists, *Negro* soon became shorthand for a member of the establishment. Prominent black publications like *Ebony* switched from *Negro* to *black* at the end of the decade, and the masses soon followed. According to a 1968 *Newsweek* poll, more than two-thirds of black Americans still preferred *Negro*, but *black* had become the majority preference by 1974. Both the Associated Press and the *New York Times* abandoned *Negro* in the 1970s, and by the mid-1980s, even the most hidebound institutions, like the U.S. Supreme Court, had largely stopped using *Negro*.

If this timing is accurate, then the frequent use of the term in a movie released in 1967 *would not have sounded unusual*, it would have simply been a reflection of the time.

It only sounds out of date to our modern ears.

The source is poor (PDF scan), but here is what Carmichael says about the term "Negro" [on page 37 of his book *Black Power*](http://sites.middlebury.edu/soan365/files/2013/02/Carmichael-Black-Power.pdf):

> Black people must redefine themselves, and only *they* can do that. Throughout this country, vast segments of the black communities are beginning to recognize the need to assert their own definitions, to reclaim their history, their culture; to create their own sense of community and togetherness. **There is a growing resentment of the word "Negro", for example, because this term is the invention of our oppressor; it is *his* image of us that he describes. Many blacks are now calling themselves African-Americans, Afro-Americans or black people because that is *our* image of ourselves.** When we begin to define our own image, the stereotypes--that is, lies--that our oppressor has developed will begin in the white community and end there. That black community will have a positive image of itself that *it* has created.

Comment: This is a good answer. I think it is worth emphasizing that the emerging hostility to _Negro_ reflected in part a generational change in tactics and leadership between establishment anti-segregationists of the 1960s and earlier and the new generation of militant activists. W.E.B. DuBois, [writing in 1928](http://www.virginia.edu/woodson/courses/aas102%20%28spring%2001%29/articles/names/dubois.htm), has an interesting exchange with a reader of _The Crisis_, two generations before the issue resurfaced in the late 1960s. To my knowledge, DuBois never abandoned his preference for the term _Negro_.

Comment: It sounds like Carmichael himself propelled "Negro" down the euphemism treadmill. One can almost see the Wikipedia annotations after "There is a growing resentment" and "Many blacks" asking for corroborating evidence.

Comment: @PaulRowe Hard to say, based on these few quotes. Probably a better question, frankly, for history.SE.

Comment: @PaulRowe I get that you were just trying to be amusing but I would say that there's only a "euphemism treadmill" here if you consider that black/negroness is *inherently* unpleasant. Calling the retarded "special" will only poison the meaning of special because retardation is inherently negative and will always poison any term for it. There's no reason that a respectful term for people of African ancestry or appearance should need to be continually adjusted.

Answer (score 7):

There is no one point when Negro stopped being used.

A now-small, mostly elderly, group of Americans still prefers to self-identify as "Negro".

For example Oscar-winning actor Louis Gossett [recently (2015) said](http://thereelnetwork.net/black-african-american-negro-who-are-we/):

> I call myself an American Negro, not an African-American

[In fact](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2013/02/25/172885551/no-more-negro-for-census-bureau-forms-and-surveys), in the 2000 census, 56,000 Americans so-preferred the term "Negro" that they refused to state they were "Black or African American" and instead stated they were "some other race" and hand-wrote that they were "Negro".

The Etymonline is wrong to say "ousted late 1960s".

As of April 1970, blacks strongly preferred "Negro" to "Black" as shown by the following Roper Louisville data, [as reported by NASA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19710019856):

> Percent of Blacks preferring to be called the following terms (April 1970):
>
> "Negro"  51%
>
> "Colored" 11%
>
> "Black" 8%
>
> "Afro-American" 8%
>
> Other 4%
>
> No difference 16%
>
> No opinion 3%

Among whites "Negro" was marginally (27% to 25%) preferred over "black" in the same poll.

NASA adds in this report, written in 1971:

> It is interesting to note that three times as many whites as Negroes seem
> to feel that it is better to use the term "black." It was pointed out in
> the article on the Louisville study that the term "black" was formerly considered to be the most derogatory of all, and this may be one reason why it
> is not appealing to Negroes. In the Louisville study, "black" was not even
> preferred by Negro youth. But in the Gallup poll, the sharpest difference
> in preference was shown between younger and older Negroes--at least in the
> North: among Negro northerners in their twenties, "black" was chosen
> either ahead of or equal to the name "Negro." Also in the same poll, the higher-income Negroes preferred "black' more often than those of lower income;
> Southerners were less likely to name "black;" and the term "Afro-American"
> was not liked at any level, remaining in the 5 to 10 percentile.

The Chicago Tribune used the term "Negro" in headlines up through 1973, perhaps the last time being [Negro elected L.A. mayor](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1973/05/30/page/1/article/negro-elected-l-a-mayor-yorty-defeated) 30 May 1973.

Some use of the term continued much longer, even though "black" and later "African-American" became preferable.

The US National Institutes of Health said in a 08 January 2015 release titled [Racial and Ethnic Categories and Definitions for NIH Diversity Programs and for Other Reporting Purposes](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/guide/notice-files/NOT-OD-15-089.html):

> Terms such as "Haitian" or "Negro" can be used

The US army stopped using the term in 2014 and Census Bureau stopped in 2013 as explained in [U.S. Army apologizes, will drop term 'Negro' from policy document](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-defense-race-language-idUSKBN0IR1W620141107) (7 November 2014).

The 2010 census gave the below form, which clearly says "Negro", to every family in the US:

[image]

The National Association for the Advancement of Colored People (NAACP) opposed changing the name of [Negro Bill Canyon](http://archive.sltrib.com/story.php?ref=/sltrib/news/55343346-78/canyon-williams-moab-negro.html.csp) as recently as 2012, one of 757 US place-names containing "Negro", the president of the Salt Lake City chapter insisting:

> Negro is an acceptable word

The 2010 article [Polls Reveal Black Americans' Contradictory Feelings On "Negro"](https://newsone.com/410452/polls-reveal-black-americans-contradictory-feelings-on-negro/) says:

> ...when the forms for the 2010 Census were released at the beginning of this year, many were surprised to see that one of the choices provided for a person’s race is “Black, African Am., or Negro.” As if that wasn’t perplexing enough, last week it was revealed that during the 2008 presidential campaign, Senate Majority Leader Harry Reid said Barack Obama was electable in part due to the fact that he is “light-skinned” and speaks “with no Negro dialect, unless he wanted to have one.”
>
> So how do Black people feel about the word? In one poll, NewsOne/Blackplanet asked members, **“Does the word ‘Negro’ offend you?” 70 percent said no**, the word does not offend them, while only 30 percent said yes.
>
> However, in a follow-up poll, we asked, “**If a white person called you a negro, would it offend you?**” and the responses almost completely switched. **67% said they would be offended**, while only 33 percent said they would not.

Comment: @Josh No way! I would only use it to refer to baseball.  References to the Negro Leagues is the most common use now.

Comment: I think the question focuses on the more common, colloquial, everyday usage of Negro vs black, rather than bureaucratic or more idiomatic usage instances.

Comment: @Josh Well it's your question, but the phrase "final blow" makes it sound very absolute.  The Chicago Tribune stopped using the term in typical headlines around 1974. http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1973/05/30/page/1/article/negro-elected-l-a-mayor-yorty-defeated "Negro elected L.A. mayor" 30 May 1973 is the last I see other than about baseball or quotations or specific organizations.

Comment: So what does Etymonline ( and others ) mean when they say the the term (Negro) was ousted by the late '60s by Black?

Comment: @Josh It's wrong by a few years.  A 1970 Roper Louisville study and 30 June 1969 Gallup poll both showed blacks preferred to be called "Negro" over "colored", "black" or "Afro-American".  The Gallup poll data was (among blacks): 38% preferred "Negro", 20% "colored", 19% "black", 10% "Afro-American".  https://books.google.com/books?id=uLGk7ERov98C&pg=PA12&dq=%22negro%22+%22colored%22+%22black%22+%22afro-american%22+gallup+1970&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip7LHL-4jUAhWMOCYKHRNJBh4Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%22negro%22%20%22colored%22%20%22black%22%20%22afro-american%22%20gallup%201970&f=false

Comment: That's interesting, you might support your view with that.

Comment: @Josh in the poll blacks were also asked which term they **least** preferred: "Negro" 11%, "colored people" 31%, "blacks" 25%, "Afro-American" 11%.  https://books.google.com/books?id=lQRHAQAAMAAJ&dq=Roper+Louisville+negro+colored&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=afro-american ; https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19710019856 I'll try to added more information to the answer.

Comment: Ironically, "Negro Bill Canyon" is a cleaned-up version of the canyon's earlier name. [_The WPA Guide to Utah_](https://books.google.com/books?id=GrPpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT392&dq=%22Bill+Canyon+(R)%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja1-v3mInUAhUp7YMKHaQsDtsQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Bill%20Canyon%20(R)%22&f=false) (1941) includes this note: "NIGGER BILL CANYON (R), 3.2 _m._, was named for William Granstaff, a mulatto who came to Moab Valley in 1877. He departed hurriedly through this canyon in 1881, when some of the white settlers charged him with contributing to Indian trouble by selling whisky. ...

Comment: ... 'The men are gathering up guns to hunt Indians," he said, as he saddled his horse, "but I think maybe I'm the Indian they're after.'"

Comment: This didn't apply to some of your examples but within a group you can use whatever term you like. Think of the reclamation of "queer", and closer to this, NWA.

Comment: You cannot use the word "Negro" in the same way you could have fifty years ago. That's an outrageous claim. Today, the word "Negro" is confined to referring to the college fund and the baseball league. Or referring to black people as a group in a historical sense. There's no other common usage today.

Comment: It takes years for new words to catch on fully. That would explain certain publications lagging behind others. In more modern times, think of "Asian" vs. "Oriental". It was OK to say either for a period of time in the 90's. But if you called an Asian person "Oriental" in the year 2000, people would look at you funny.

Comment: @Ringo Publications led the change, initially against the will of the majority of Blacks.  "Negro Digest" changed its name to "Black World" in 1970 when the above data show that Blacks still had an overwhelming preference for the term "Negro".

Comment: @DavePhD This makes sense, some publications would lead the charge, and others would lag years behind.

Comment: @Ringo And some haven't changed yet, like the Journal of Negro Education.  http://www.journalnegroed.org/ and The Negro Educational Review Journal http://www.uncfsu.edu/ner

Comment: @DavePhD That's the title of the publication. If they use the word Negro instead of black IN that publication, then I would agree with you.

Comment: @Ringo I'm sure the individual authors of the articles can choose which word they want to use.  "Negro Digest" led by changing its name in 1970, while other journals decided to keep their historical names.  The Journal of Negro History changed its name in 2002.  http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/serial?id=jnegrohistory

Comment: I strongly disagree. There is no writer today using the word "Negro" in their writing, save for maybe a very old Ku Klux Klan member.

Comment: If you can find one, I will surely eat crow.

Comment: @Ringo of course respectable authors still use the term.  Hundreds of instances in this 2009 book https://books.google.com/books?id=P_VzVwDdzn0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Just+The+Typical+American+Negro&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiuuHbx47UAhUr04MKHQOYA6oQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=negro&f=false

Comment: I looked over these examples, and they all seem to use "Negro" in a historical context. But of course you must know this.

Comment: Your answer may be technically correct, but in spirit it is misleading to the OP.

Comment: @Ringo The book says "The Negro is told they are black to keep in place an establishment condition" (page 29); "The white American male will call the light skinned Negro black.  Reaching back into the genetic poll, the poor light skinned Negro will agree with white America and call himself black." (page 110).

Comment: I appreciate your tenacity, but once again, I think your quote uses "Negro" in a historical perspective. I can admit that you might be correct in a strictly academic sense if you could admit that it is wrong in a practical sense. For you to claim that people today are commonly using the word "Negro" instead of "black" is clearly wrong and deliberately misleading -- in my humble opinion. This is a site where people come to learn stuff -- it ought not be some place where scholars put technical minutiae before practical knowledge.

Comment: Im pretty sure I've spoken more than enough -- so I will stop contradicting you here... Thanks for reading.

Comment: @Ringo My answers concludes in boldface "67% said they would be offended" if a white person called them a Negro.  I don't see how anyone reading my whole answer would be mislead into misusing the word.  I say "Black" and I strongly recommend saying "Black" in most circumstances.

Comment: I very much doubt the accuracy of that poll, at least in the United States. A non-black person would be considered racist for calling someone a Negro today. Or in 2010.

Comment: @Josh They mean that Etymonline is **not** a reliable source. It is, at best, a free look at the *OED*'s etymologies and it is not always at its best.

Comment: @Ringo You're generally correct in your resistance here but *(a)* there is some nuance: the blacks in the survey had less initial resistance to the term because they know that grampa still proudly distinguishes himself as a negro. Many will make the same allowance for most respectful elderly white people, while at the same time assuming that any elderly white people are inherently rather racist by default. *(b)* British usage on "Asian" v "Oriental" is completely different from America's, since their "Asian" tends to refer to Desi immigrants.

Comment: @Ringo The book I cited, is about "the modern decision to be called black" quoting this review: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/reviews/just-the-typical-american-negro-jun-louise-briggs-dehorney/1018885510?ean=9781438993812#reviews-header The author does not choose the word "Negro" for historical context.  The author, whose father was a light-skinned Negro, is speaking out against use of the term "black" and you are disrespecting the author's choice to self-identify as Negro, and to express a preference for the term "Negro".

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the 1960s black was an offensive term often used as an adjective as in, “you black something-else-offensive”.  Negro (capitalized) was the polite, respectful term.  About this time Negroes became sensitive to the fact that they are more or less intrinsically black.  Thus it was asserted that “black is beautiful” (black not capitalized).  And so it is.

Comment: What about the movie? That is what this question focuses on; I think you should mention it specifically

Comment: @sumelic but the movie itself cannot deal a final blow; it could be people's reactions to it that dealt a final blow (but I doubt people's reactions to any movie have dealt a final blow to anything).

Comment: @sumelic I agree with Clare that that part of the question is rather patently and inherently wrong-headed. Every answer doesn't need to start with a variation of "Of course not, silly"; "How would you even prove that"; and "In what universe do you imagine a successful and respectful movie would undo its own diction choices?" The usage-of-negro part is still a good question to ask and this is a good (if anecdotal) answer to it.